# Spring MVC Formatter won't call parse function when POSTing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have implemented a very basic Date Formatter in my Spring MVC application and the formatter works fine when printing the date.  However, when I POST a java.util.Date value to a controller that is invalid (which I want to handle with the code below), I get a 500 error (below).  The logging that I have setup in the parse() function does not get called leading me to believe I am missing something with my configuration.  Essentially I would like unparseable Strings to Dates to be treated as nulls.

DateFormatter.java

```
@Service
 public class DateFormatter implements Formatter<Date> {
private final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(DateFormatter.class);

public DateFormatter() {
    super();
}

@Override
public String print(Date object, Locale locale) {
    LOG.debug("printing date: " + object);
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = createDateFormat();
    return dateFormat.format(object);
}

@Override
public Date parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    LOG.debug("Parsing date: " + text);
    if (text==null || text.isEmpty()) return null;
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = createDateFormat();
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(text);
    LOG.debug("Parsed date: " + date);
    return date;
}

private SimpleDateFormat createDateFormat() {
    String format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    return dateFormat;
}
```

}

My WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements the formatter as follows:

```
public class WebMvcConfigurerAdapterImpl extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 .....
 @Autowired
DateFormatter dateFormatter;

 @Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    LOG.debug("Adding formatters!!!");        
    registry.addFormatter(dateFormatter);
}
 .....
 }
```

I have very basic controllers for this test:

```
 .....
 @RequestMapping(value="/test2",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test2(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("testDate", new Date());
    return "thymeleaf/test-view";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/test2",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String test2post(@RequestParam Date dateIn) {
    System.out.println("here: " + dateIn);
    return "thymeleaf/test-view";
}
```

My view (Thymeleaf) looks like the following (sorry about the code snippet):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p th:text="${{testDate}}"></p>
 <form th:action="@{/test2}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="dateIn"></input>
  <input type="submit"></input>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to the test2 controller (GET) the print() function works and "testDate" gets formatted correctly.

When I POST the form with no value in the text input I get a 500 error and the parse() function is not called.

**Shouldn't the parse() function of the custom Formatter be called when the form is posted to the controller since it is expecting a value of type Date?**

Error:

org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

```
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:71)
org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:45)
org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:595)
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:102)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:685)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:164)
net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:202)
net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:180)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:119)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
```

Comment: Turn your logs to DEBUG.

Comment: Updated question.  Got the logs outputting

Comment: Are you getting your log 'Adding formatters'? Can you please print the value over there to make sure it is not null?

Comment: I am getting the "adding formatters" log entry on application startup.   It would not have a value at the time of initialization.